# How to create an application that connects host device with Gear device and then transfer data from host device to Gear device in Tizen for wearable

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I have read and understand the sample HelloAccessory of Samsung. In this sample, users will click the Connect button on Gear device to connect with the service on host device, and then click the Fetch button on Gear device to send and receive data from host device. I want to create an application that user will click Connect button on host device to connect with Gear device and then click Send button on host device to send data from host device to Gear device. How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the Tizen Bluetooth Device APIs. (Search for tizen.bluetooth.abc in the tau.js source code.)

However the feature is not supported in the emulator currently so you will need an actual device to test.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in FileTransfer and Gallery sample apps from the same Accessory SDK? I think the Gallery is much more like what you need.

Yet, of course, you could require much modification depending on what exactly do you mean by your "data" and how you process it on the host side and wearable side.

I think HelloAccessory is a way too simple and is not a good starting point for your task.

Answer (score 0):

The protocol for doing this is called Samsung Accessory Protocol , I am afraid that in current version there are no Open BT/BTLE Api exposed to developer.

Check FileTransfer_150212.zip from

http://developer.samsung.com/sample-app/view.do?v=S000000049

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/790774/Utilize-the-Accessory-File-Transfer-on-Samsung-Gea